# Finding all CLASSPATH resources matching a pattern

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I want to read a bunch of text files, by loading them as resources using the context classloader.

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource("folder/foo.txt");
```

Is there some way to get a list of resources whose names match a given pattern? For eg:

```
URL[] matchingUrls = someLibrary.getMatchingResources("folder/*.txt");
```

Libraries like Spring can scan the classpath to find classes with a given annotation, so I am wondering if there something similar to load a bunch of resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring supports ant-style class path resource matching.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/resources.html

Examples like : `classpath:com/mycompany/**/applicationContext.xml, /WEB-INF/*-context.xml`

See if you can use spring for your project. If it is not possible then you can always pull down the source code to see what they are doing, and do that yourself :)

Comment: org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java seems to be the class doing the work. I cannot use Spring in my application, though. :(

Answer (score 17):

Just use:

```
@Value("classpath:folder/*.xml")
Resource[] resources;
```

Comment: I've needed this three of four time in the past year, and this is by far the best solution I've come across. OP nixed spring, but this trick sure makes it easy to get patterns of resources from the classpath, and works great for my situation.

Comment: When I do this with List<Resource> in Spring 5, I get for example, `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [folder/*.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`. @whitestryder 's solution below did however work.

Answer (score 13):

Comment from "Binil Thomas" was on the right track, I was looking for confirmation that Spring's PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver could be used from Java Config so that I could give the resulting "Resource" list to the Spring Hibernate SessionFactory.mappingLocations without having to update the list of Hibernate *.hbm.xml files every time a new mapping file was added.  I was able to achieve this with the PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver using the below code:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
...
ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();   
Resource [] mappingLocations = patternResolver.getResources("classpath*:mappings/**/*.hbm.xml");
sessionFactory.setMappingLocations(mappingLocations);
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

You can try corn-cps

```
 List<URL> resources = CPScanner.scanResources(new PackageNameFilter("net.sf.corn.cps.*"), new ResourceNameFilter("*.xml"));
```

Use the dependecy below in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.corn</groupId>
    <artifactId>corn-cps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```