# How should I store text files in a Java program to easily read them?

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm making a program that takes multiple choice questions in the form of several text files, reads them, and then quizzes the user.

I put the text files in a package, and used the `File` type to access the package and then read all of the files in the directory, but it wouldn't read the files when I ran the `.jar` file (it worked during testing). I then tried using `InputStream` and it works now, but I have to specify the file name of each text file. Is there anyway I can use InputStream to read all the files in a directory, or is there an alternate solution I should try?

Comment: Could you add some example code of how you read the files?  Also, are the files' package inside the jar or in a folder next to it?

Comment: You might consider storing the entire set of questions as a single YAML file and reading them using SnakeYAML.

Comment: Currently reading the files as such:
`InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/package/file.txt);`
then using a buffered reader, the files' package is in the jar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all CLASSPATH resources matching a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766933/finding-all-classpath-resources-matching-a-pattern)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe having the files in an external folder would be easier to manage and also some consider it bad practice to have files other than code in their main source folder. If you are worried about people opening and reading the files, just apply some kind of encoding. Here is how I would access external folders:

1. Create a folder to place all your text files in. Lets name it "questions". This folder can be placed in your project folder and later just copied and pasted to be next to the JAR file.
2. Create a new source (`src`) folder in your project named resources and create a new package named "`res`". In the `res` package, create a class named `ResourceLoader`. This class will be used to access external files and folders by using the user directory i.e. the folder the JAR is in.

The class:

```
public class ResourceLoader {

    private static final String QUESTION_FOLDERNAME = "questions";    

    /**
    * Returns the folder containing all the questions
    *
    */
    public static File getQuestionsFolder(){
        String userDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println(userDirectory+"\\"+QUESTION_FOLDERNAME); 

        return new File(userDirectory+"\\"+QUESTION_FOLDERNAME);
    }

}
```

Now you can access this folder and read like the following:

```
File folder = ResourceLoader.getQuestionsFolder();

for(File f : folder.listFiles()){

  // Read the text file...

}
```

Your project structure should look something like this:

[image]